Encrypting Github secrets using Python via Rest API - issues locally vs lambda
I am trying to encrypt an AWS CodeArtifact JWT via Github Rest API and  then upload this as a Github secret to Dependabot and Actions via an AWS Lambda.
The code flow is:

Retrieve CodeArtifact Token with 12 hour duration.

Retrieve public keys for Dependabot and Actions.

Encrypt using the below function.

Update secret via Github Rest API.
For encryption I use the PyNacl library and follow this guide: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/encrypting-secrets-for-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28


My encryption function looks like this:
from base64 import b64encode
from nacl import encoding, public

def encrypt(public_key: str, secret_value: str) -> str:
  """Encrypt a Unicode string using the public key."""
  public_key = public.PublicKey(public_key.encode("utf-8"), encoding.Base64Encoder())
  sealed_box = public.SealedBox(public_key)
  encrypted = sealed_box.encrypt(secret_value.encode("utf-8"))
  return b64encode(encrypted).decode("utf-8")

encrypt("YOUR_BASE64_KEY", "YOUR_SECRET")

Locally when I run the code it works perfectly, I am using Python 3.12 and running a venv to ensure I have the dependencies from my requirements.txt only.
When I run the code from my Lambda it returns all normal status codes and seems to work however authentication fails when using the Github Dependabot and Actions secrets from this lambda run.
From my Lambda I have confirmed I can retrieve both the CodeArtifact token and public keys, I also can encrypt without error using the same function and upload to Github secrets fine.
I think the issue might be with my Docker container, i am using this image.
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10

I've tested using a python:3.10-slim image locally and that works as well.
The Docker container is part of a CI/CD process so can't be changed that easily as its reusable for my Infrastructure.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What nacl library do you have installed in the docker image? Is it py-nacl or libnacl? What version of libsodium is used in the lambda image? Can you share the output of nacl.__version__ ?
